# Azure Devops Build Issue missing folders

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2603,5):
>   Error : Copying file
>   app\bower_components\bootstrap-switch\node_modules\jquery\AUTHORS.txt
>   to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\app\bower_components\bootstrap-switch\node_modules\jquery\AUTHORS.txt
>   failed. Could not find a part of the path
>   'app\bower_components\bootstrap-switch\node_modules\jquery\AUTHORS.txt'.
>
> Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Comment: Hi, when you build locally in visual studio does it work ok? Or it is only in Azure DevOps that it fails? Could we have a screen shot of the directory structure in visual studio please? Feel free to mask the screenshot it if you don't want the directory structure to be public on stackoverflow.

Comment: Here's some helpful tips on structuring stackoverflow questions to attract the most helpful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AUTHORS.txt` properties like below. Right-click the `Authors.txt` file go to `properties` then change the

`Build Action` to **`None`** 
 
`Copy to Output Directory` to **`Copy always`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
It is working now without any issue.